# recv failed if socket fd more than 1024 in cpp linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, client

In my project i am using open close (server and client c++ Linux multithreading  ) model every time client create socket file descriptor  and send data to server and receive wait for response.in this process after some transactions rec v failed. for this i observed  socket file descriptor is more than 1024. but i was set max allowed file descriptors at Linux operating system level 8192. And also i was observed one more thing  by using thisis (netstat -an|grep "PORT NUMBER") command socket connections are observed those are less connections (< 300). my connection pool size is 100 only . In this few of connections close_wait state.

How to over come this issue .please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

1024 is the usual definition of `FD_SETSIZE` from sys/select.h (on my system, deeply included from bits/typesizes.h)

If you're using `select`, you should stop and use `poll` or `epoll` instead, since they don't require a hard-coded limit at compile-time, only the runtime limit on maximum number of open files.

Comment: hi sir, earlier days i used to select only. same problem facing with select also

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are leaking some other file descriptor, and not necessarily your socket's file descriptor. You're probably leaving some file open, probably. Look into `/proc/<pid>/fd`, which will list all open file descriptors for the given process.

Comment: hi sir, i observed actual transactions was 100 per sec in my test env but always is shows arround 300 to 400 connections (except db connections. including DB connections is shows 300+DB connections size ). actually my application connect with DB through proc blocks. But same applications working fine with lower versions of red hat Linux at that time my application never meet's 1024 socket fd

Comment: Who said anything about "transactions"? What part of "Look into /proc/<pid>/fd" you were not able to understand?

Comment: hi sir,my actual issue with multi threading case only. I understood what your shared sir